# Use information about selectInput within a renderUI

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I want to use some information of a `selectInput` in a `renderUi`, e.g. the length of selected items (renderUi depends on this number).
Unfortunately I haven't find a solution yet. Below a short simplified example, which should display the length of selected items. I guess there is a problem  either with the return type of input or with the encoding of I/O.

Please note: I tried already `renderPrint`, which is working! But I need the information about the length of selectInput within a renderUi, since I want to create further ui elements based on the selected number.

Ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  selectInput("first","first",choices=c("a","b"),multiple=TRUE),
  uiOutput("hallo")
))
```

Server.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$hallo <- renderUI({
    print(length(input$first))
  })

})
```

Comment: If you use `paste` instead of `print`, it will return the value.

Comment: yes, seems to work. Could you be so kind and give a short explanation why it does not work with print?

Comment: Its not the `paste/print` that was throwing errors. Read about $ operator (`?'$'`)

Comment: @Sagar, this does not work:  > ?'$'
Warning message:
In find.package(if (is.null(package)) loadedNamespaces() else package,  :
  there is no package called ‘foo’